# Redirect from plugin in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

So I made a plugin for `Magento\Framework\App\FrontControllerInterface`

I want to redirect from cookie called `preferred_country` as value the specific store id

If the store id doesn't match the current store needs to be redirected.

```php
    /**
     * @param FrontController $subject
     * @param Closure $proceed
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @return ResponseInterface|mixed
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function aroundDispatch(FrontController $subject, Closure $proceed, RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $preferred_cookie = $this->getFirstStoreCookie();

        if ($preferred_cookie) {

            $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

            if ($store != $preferred_cookie) {

                $redirectUrl = 'https://magento2-4-3-p1.test/de/';

                $response = $this->_responseFactory->create();
                $response->setRedirect($redirectUrl, 301);
                $response->setNoCacheHeaders();

                return $response;

            }
        }
        $request->setDispatched(false);

        return $proceed($request);
    }
```

When I dump `$response` the output is `HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently Location: https://magento2-4-3-p1.test/nl/ Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store Expires: Wed, 05 May 2021 09:38:31 GMT` So thats correct, but I doesn't redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the storeManager to redirect to a different store, something like this should do it with little adaptation required. You need to pass the store manager object on your plugin contructor and the use the code in the observer snippet.

**vendor\module\etc\events.xml**

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="controller_action_predispatch" instance="vendor\module\Observer\PreDespatchEvent" />
    </event>
```

In the observer

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class PreDespatchEvent implements ObserverInterface
{  
    
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_customerSession;
    

    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) 
    {
        $this->_storeManager    = $storeManager;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }
    

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        storeIdTOredirect = //GetStore Id
        $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($storeIdTOredirect);
        $url = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
        header("Location: $url");
        exit;       
                
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Does this also work with websites in Magento? I have like different website with one store in each.

Comment: yes, this is done using my own magento store.

Comment: It works, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem ;) Glad I could help !